# Qt: How to know when a QMdiSubWindow is closed?

Tags: qt

Is there any way I can get notified when a user closes a QMdiSubWindow? I cannot find any signal in [QMdiArea](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html) nor in [QMdiSubWindow](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmdisubwindow.html) that suggests I can.

I think my only chance is by subclassing QMdiSubWindow and overriding the close event, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any other way than as you describe (overriding the close event) to do precisely what you're asking.

There might be other ways of achieving what you want without doing that depending on why you want to know when its closed.  Other options could be the use of the [destroyed](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#destroyed) signal, checking [QApplication::focusWidget()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#focusWidget), or perhaps having the parent inspect its [children](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#children).

**Edit in response to comment:**

Signals and slots are disconnected automatically upon destruction of QObjects, and I would suggest looking at using [QSharedPointers](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html) or [QScopedPointers](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qscopedpointer.html) to handle your QObjects' lifespans instead.  By applying these techniques, you shouldn't need a signal from a closed window.

Comment: I need to clean some connections between signals/slots and delete some objects.

Comment: I just wanted to add that using the `destroyed()` signal to access the QMdiSubWindow is dangerous (i.e. connect the `destroyed()` signal to a slot, and then in the slot cast the `sender()` to a QMdiSubWindw) because the `destroyed()` signal is emitted in the QObject's destructor. That means that by the time the `destroyed()` signal is emitted, the QMdiSubWindow's destructor has already been called.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is another way : you can install an event-filter on the QMdiSubWindow you create :

```
MdiSubWindowEventFilter * p_mdiSubWindowEventFilter;

...

QMdiSubWindow * subWindow = mdiArea->addSubWindow(pEmbeddedWidget);
subWindow->installEventFilter(p_mdiSubWindowEventFilter);
subWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true); // not mandatory, depends if you manage subWindows lifetime
```

with

```
bool MdiSubWindowEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * e)
{
    switch (e->type())
    {
        case QEvent::Close:
        {
            QMdiSubWindow * subWindow = dynamic_cast<QMdiSubWindow*>(obj);
            Q_ASSERT (subWindow != NULL);

            //
            // do what you want here
            //

            break;
        }
        default:
            qt_noop();
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same trouble, but in my case the task was more specific: "How to hide a subwindow when I press the close button instead of closing". So I solved this with the following:

```
subwindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, false);
```

Perhaps it's not a relevant answer but it may be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended coding.

```
#ifndef __MYSUBWINDOW_H
#define __MYSUBWINDOW_H

#include <QMdiSubWindow>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QDebug>

class MyQMdiSubWindow : public QMdiSubWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void closed( const QString );

protected:
    void closeEvent( QCloseEvent * closeEvent )
    {
        emit closed( this->objectName() );
        closeEvent->accept();
    }
};
#endif
```

Note that for my problem I need a way to identify which subwindow user is closing, and objectName does the work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create QWidget based class like:

```
class CloseWatcher : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

private:
  QString m_name;

signals:
  void disposing( QString name );

public
  CloseWatcher( QWidget * p )
    : QWidget( p )
    , m_name( p->objectName() )
  {}

  ~CloseWatcher()
  {
    emit disposing( m_name );
  }
};
```

and just use it:

```
// anywhere in code
QMdiSubWindow * wnd = getSomeWnd();
CloseWatcher * watcher = new CloseWatcher( wnd );

connect( watcher, SIGNAL( disposing( QString ) ), reveiver, SLOT( onDispose( QString ) ) );
```